# Why my .cs and .designer.cs files doesn't appears under my uitest files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

After a refactoring some of my files doesn't appears anymore under my uitest structure in Visual Studio. Everything works fine. I can build, test and create new action in my uitest files.

The correct structure is

```
- UIMaps
  - RequestPage.uitest
    - RequestPage.cs
    - RequestPage.Designer.cs
  - LoginPage.uitest
    - LoginPage.cs
    - LoginPage.Designer.cs
```

I have this

```
- UIMaps
  - RequestPage.cs
    - RequestPage.Designer.cs
  - RequestPage.uitest
  - LoginPage.cs
    - LoginPage.Designer.cs
  - LoginPage.uitest
```

How can I recreate the correct structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to edit your `.csproj` manually, something like this:

```
[...]
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="RequestPage.cs">
    <DependentUpon>RequestPage.uitest</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="RequestPage.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>RequestPage.uitest</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
[...]
```